# Filling a list in Python with n identical terms

Tags: python, list

I'd like to fill a list with as many underscores as there are letters in a word. I can use a loop such as:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
```

To populate the list with underscores, but it feels like extremely bad coding. Is there a nicer/higher level alternative?

Comment: oh yes: `['_'] * len(word)`. Do you want that as a string?

Answer (score 2):

You need to just multiply the single underscore `list` with length of your word. For example, on multiplying the list with `int` 10 gives:

```
>>> ['_'] * 10
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

For finding the length of word, use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function which:

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

For example:

```
>>> len('Hello')
5
```

Hence, your final code could be written as:

```
>>> ['_'] * len('Hello')
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`[ '_' ] * len(word)`

multiplying a list by a number yields a new list with the elements repeated that many times.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is by splitting the string and using len() to multiply "_":

```
st = "infidel niemcy said God is kill"
print [ "_"*len(word) for word in st.split()]
```